# Fastlane Support on Windows

Tags: xamarin, fastlane

I'm doing some investigation into potentially using Fastlane in our build chain.

We would only be looking to use it for beta deployments so we would only need to use `supply` and `pilot`.

Because our apps are written using Xamarin some of our build machines are Windows based so I'm trying to asses the level of support for Windows in Fastlane.

I understand that the CLI tools are Ruby based so in theory they can run on Windows but does anyone have any experience of using `supply` and `pilot` on Windows?

Comment: Why bother Stack Overflow when there are tons of discussions at GitHub already? https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/search?q=xamarin&type=Issues&utf8=✓

Answer (score 2):

Windows is not an officially supported platform for *fastlane* right now, sorry!

While Ruby does run on Windows, some of its classes and methods are not compatible with Windows, and *fastlane* does use some of those incompatible APIs.

Comment: Hi, is it still not supported?